# Is there a way to filter the one drop-down based on another drop down using pure javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have two fields 'Controller Type' and 'Test Type'. What i want is that when controller is 'EBOD' the tests which should be coming in the dropdown are ('BFT','CTO','JBOD Generic'). I tried doing that using javascript but couldn't get an effective solution. Can anyone please help to achieve this?
Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks

```
<fieldset>
                <label for='Controller Type'><strong>Controller Type </strong></label>
                <select name='controller' id="Controller" onchange="showsecondlist()" required>
                    <option value=""> - Select the Controller - </option>
                    <option data-extra=true value='RAID'>RAID
                    <option data-extra=true value='EBOD'>EBOD
                    <option data-extra=true value='AP'>AP
                </select>
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset>
                <label for='Test Type'><strong>Test Type</strong></label>
                <select name='test' id="Test" required >
                    <option value=""> - Select The Test - </option>
                    <option data-extra=true value='BFT'>BFT
                    <option data-extra=true value='CTO'>CTO
                    <option data-extra=true value='RAID Generic'>RAID Generic
                    <option data-extra=true value='Port Check' >Port Check
                    <option data-extra=true value='FW Generic' >FW Generic
                    <option data-extra=true value='EBOD Generic' >JBOD Generic
                </select>
            </fieldset>
```

I tried something like this, which didn't work.

```
function showsecondlist()
{
var uservalue= document.getElementById("Controller").value;
if(uservalue=='EBOD')
document.getElementById("Test").value.innerHTML='<option value="1.1">BFT</option><option value="1.2">CTO</option><option value="1.2">JBOD Generic</option>';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use sth. like the following:

```js
// mapping from values of first select to the ones
// to be shown in second when that value is selected
const mappings = {
  a: ['d','e'],
  b: ['e','f'],
  c: ['d','g']
};
const first = document.getElementById('first');
const second = document.getElementById('second');

// when first select changes, show all options of the second,
// if no mapping exists, otherwise show mapped and hide the others
first.onchange = ({ target: { value: selected }}) => {      
  [...second.options].forEach((o) => {
    if (!mappings[selected] || mappings[selected].includes(o.value)) {
      o.style.display = '';    
    } else {
      o.style.display = 'none';
    } 
  });
};
```

```html
<label>
  First select:
  <select id="first">
    <option>...</option>
    <option>a</option>
    <option>b</option>
    <option>c</option>
    <option>d</option>
  </select>
</label>

<label>
  Second select:
  <select id="second">
    <option>d</option>
    <option>e</option>
    <option>f</option>
    <option>g</option>
  </select>
</label>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response but I am getting an error 'Cannot set property 'onchange' of null' while implementing this. Can you help me fix this?

Comment: @Jayashri I can try. When are you including the script? The element being `null` indicates to me it's not in the DOM yet, so maybe adding `defer` to the script or moving it to the bottom of the page will help. Another way might be to do the work shown here inside a listener on the `window` object's DOMContentLoaded event.

Comment: I have added the code which I tried. I had included the code at the end while it was giving an error. I have put the code now in my changehandler and its giving me error like 'second.options is not iterable
    at HTMLSelectElement.first.onchange'. Note that these fieldsets are part of a form. Can you please help me achieve this for my form?

Comment: @Jayashri Your code was almost working! You need to remove `.value` from `second` and then there also is a typo in either the value or textContent of 'EBOD Generic' (one is written with J).